# Rename a computer programmatically

Tags: c#, java, python, hostname

I need to automate the changing of the hostname of a computer, but I can't figure out how to do it inside a program. My options are open; I would be happy with a solution in any of the following:

Command line
Java
Python
C# (would prefer one of the other 3, but this is ok)

It would be helpful to learn how to do this on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Windows? Linux? You said hostname, so I guess it may be a *nix but then you mentioned C#? is it Windows?

Comment: I would ask this question on serverfault.com.  Once you have a command line solution the programming is trivial.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: this is only true on non-Windows systems. In Windows you are not supposed to use the command line to do administrative tasks...

Comment: @Lorenzo:  No offense, but I have never heard that before.  Do you have any MSDN or other documentation to cite?

Comment: @Brian: it is obvious if you have ever used Windows. It is almost impossible to administer (or use) just with command line, as Windows isn't a collection of command line tools and configuration files like UNIX. In Windows configuration is often doable only trough the GUI. Now it is changing a bit with PowerShell and Windows Management Infrastructure (WMI).

Answer (score 3):

For Unix-based systems:

Command line:

```
$ hostname "host.domain.com"
```

Python (sort of):

```
import os
os.system('hostname "host.domain.com"')
```

Comment: And, depending on the system/flavor/distribution, will revert to something stored in a file somewhere when you reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in powershell on windows. Seems safer to me than changing registry keys by hand :

```
$computer = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -OriginalPCname OriginalName -computername $originalPCName
$computer.Rename("NEWCOMPUTERNAME")
}
```

see [this](http://poshcode.org/541) poshcode page

Comment: How can you do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you have to modify registry keys and the reboot the system.

You actually have to change two entries:

`HostName` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters`

and

`ComputerName` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName`

Please note that if the computer ha joined an NT Domain this change could be harmful (and in this case you have an additional entry to change under `TcpIp\Parameters`).

Comment: Ok cool, a couple of questions:

1. The ComputerName entry is all caps. When I change it should I also put the name in all caps?

2. What if I want to change the DNS suffix. Where would that be located?

Thanks.